# Python:Convert list to dict for assign specific data to variable

Tags: python

Code:

```
a={'day': [{'average_price': 9.3,
   'buy_m2m': 9.3,
   'buy_price': 9.3,
   'buy_quantity': 1,
   'buy_value': 9.3,
   'close_price': 0,
   'exchange': 'NSE',
   'instrument_token': 2867969,
   'last_price': 9.3,
   'm2m': 0.0,
   'multiplier': 1,
   'net_buy_amount_m2m': 9.3,
   'net_sell_amount_m2m': 0,
   'overnight_quantity': 0,
   'pnl': 0.0,
   'product': 'MIS',
   'quantity': 1,
   'realised': 0,
   'sell_m2m': 0,
   'sell_price': 0,
   'sell_quantity': 0,
   'sell_value': 0,
   'tradingsymbol': 'SUBEX',
   'unrealised': 0.0,
   'value': -9.3}],
 'net': [{'average_price': 9.3,
   'buy_m2m': 9.3,
   'buy_price': 9.3,
   'buy_quantity': 1,
   'buy_value': 9.3,
   'close_price': 0,
   'exchange': 'NSE',
   'instrument_token': 2867969,
   'last_price': 9.3,
   'm2m': 0.0,
   'multiplier': 1,
   'net_buy_amount_m2m': 9.3,
   'net_sell_amount_m2m': 0,
   'overnight_quantity': 0,
   'pnl': 0.0,
   'product': 'MIS',
   'quantity': 1,
   'realised': 0,
   'sell_m2m': 0,
   'sell_price': 0,
   'sell_quantity': 0,
   'sell_value': 0,
   'tradingsymbol': 'SUBEX',
   'unrealised': 0.0,
   'value': -9.3}]}
b= a['day']
```

`a` shows dict type variable in python. I want to assign value of `buy_price` which is `9.3` to variable ``x and value of `instrument_token` which is `2867969` to variable `y`.

Now problem is after using `b=a['day']`, `b` variable becomes list in python so I can not use `x=b['buy_price']` to get `x=9.3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about x=b[0]['buy_price'] ?

Comment: Amicsbile and @ Ching Li It works.Thank you very much :) !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = b[0]['buy_price']

y = b[0]['instrument_token']
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now problem is after using b=a['day'], b variable becomes list

It doesn't "become" a list, it's already one: look at your `a` dict, `a['day']` IS a list - containing one single dict.

> so I can not use x=b['buy_price']

Obviously not. `buy_price` is a key in the dict contained by `a['day']`, so you must first reference that dict using `b[0]`, and then you can get the keys you want, ie `b[0]['buy_price']`.